# Unable to redirect to new VF page

Tags: visualforce, pagereference, redirect

I'm trying to capture **orderid**  from URL and then redirect user to a different visualforce page **OrderTrackingClass** after finding the **orderId**
Following is what I tried...

```
public with sharing class redirectOrderPartner{

public String currentRecordId {get;set;}
public orders__c orderId {get;set;}

public redirectOrderPartner(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

currentRecordId  = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('orderid');

    orderId = [select id from orders__c where name =: currentRecordId limit 1];

    system.debug('---orderid---'+orderId);
 }
 Public Pagereference go(){
    PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/OrderTrackingClass?id={!orderId}');
    pageRef.setRedirect(true);
   // return pageRef;
   }
```

and in Visualforce page I addded ...

```
    <apex:page standardcontroller="orders__c" extensions="redirectOrderPartner" action="{!go}">
```

The debug logs are showing correct results. But I'm being redirected to

> www.somesite/apex/OrderTrackingClass?id=+%7B%21orderId%7D

I guess my syntax for **pageRef** is incorrect.

Please guide me. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong. You don't have to use visualforce syntax in apex for variables:

```
PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/OrderTrackingClass?id=' + orderId.id);
```